# Meteor Error: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'component.jsx'

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

I have a problem that has absolutely stumped me.

I've got a Meteor/React application I've been developing for a week. Everything is running fine on my desktop. I grabbed my MacBook today, pulled the code from Github and went to run it.

The app throws the error in the JavaScript console:

`modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:139`

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../ui/components/signin/Signin.jsx'
    at Function.require.resolve (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:139)
    at Module.resolve (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:91)
    at Module.Mp.import (printer.js:170)
    at meteorInstall.imports.startup.client.routes.jsx (routes.jsx:1)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
    at Module.Mp.import (printer.js:170)
    at meteorInstall.imports.startup.client.index.js (index.js:1)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
```

I cloned the application to a new folder on my desktop and I get the same problem there too. I've removed all references to the Signin.jsx module but I just get the error thrown for other modules too.

I have no idea what is causing this, the app works perfectly in my original development directory but as soon as I pull it in to a new directory I get this error in the JS console.

I have tried:

```
meteor reset
meteor npm rebuild
meteor npm install
meteor update
```

None of them have made any difference. Your help is much appreciated!

## EDIT

When I run `meteor npm install` in the new directory I get the following error that may have something to do with the problem?

```
> bcrypt@1.0.2 install /Users/s/Desktop/calendar/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v46-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.2 and node@4.6.2 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bcrypt_lib.node
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
  COPY /Users/s/Desktop/calendar/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
```

Comment: are you sure the casing is correct? `'../../ui/components/signin/Signin.jsx' doublecheck that your import / require statements use the exact capital casing as the actual file. Also can you post a piece of code where you were importing that component?

Comment: Yeah the casing is perfect. The application works 100% perfectly in the original directory I am developing in, it's only when I clone it to a new directory that it breaks (this makes me think the problem is something to do with the node_modules folder as it isn't pushed to github.

Check my edit!

Comment: Before running npm install, please delete the local folder within .meteor folder.

Comment: I figured it out guys, thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what the problem was. I had renamed some files a few days ago to change them to be exactly the same as the name of the React Components they contained.

So for example - I renamed signin.jsx -> Signin.jsx

For some reason, github didn't notice this change on a few files so when I pushed the repo, some of my imports were broken.

That's why the app worked perfectly in my directory but not in any cloned directories.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Wow, I had this exact same problem! Thanks for helping me get to the root of it. I guess I won't be so trusting of git to do everything magically, moving forward.

Comment: Glad someone is still learning from my issues from 4 years ago haha

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Running Instance Everytime Created Folder is

> ./meteor/Local

Please Delete this Folder .

If Your Change Project Directory,Don't Kepp this Folder. If Using **git** ,initialaize git at the time created gitignore file created .This During git push Local Folder Removed .